# Aspx page rendering SmartTarget <tcdl> tags

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, smarttarget, tcdl

In my ASP.NET website I'm finding that my [tcdl] tags related to SmartTarget content are not being converted, but are being served 'as is' in the page HTML.

I've tried the following:

1) I've gone through the installation doc, paying particular attention to [Configuring Content Delivery](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/concept_20D3832063C443339E9BAFF84F2574E4) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)), but this doesn't seem to help.

2) Checked our working environment (this was ST 2009, the none working is now ST 2011 SP2) as I'm pretty sure that I'm missing a TCDL related JAR, but when I compare with other environments that are working, the JAR is in place.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably missing the tagbundle configuration in the cd_deployer_conf.xml

You need to add the following to the <TCDLEngine> section of the deployer:

```
<TagBundle Resource="com/tridion/smarttarget/tcdl/tagbundle.xml" />
```

More information [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2/task_8ABA97C8501B41819E2519AAD527A24D).

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a Deployer configuration issue to me, rather than a WebApp/Broker issue. Double check you have the Smart Target tag bundle in the TCDLEngine element of your Deployer config.

Comment: Jumping on the bandwagon with the answer - but indeed you are right, so you get my vote too xxx

Answer (score 8):

Just checking and comparing with my (working) ST box.

Do you have a Processors configured in the deployer's cd_deployer_conf.xml?

```
<Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction">
  <Module Type="SmartTargetDeploy" Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule">
    <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
  </Module>
</Processor>
<Processor Action="Undeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction">
  <Module Type="SmartTargetUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperUndeployModule"/>
</Processor>
```

And a tagbundle?

```
<TagBundle Resource="com/tridion/smarttarget/tcdl/tagbundle.xml"/>
```

**Update**: Oops, didn't read Nuno's reply yet.

Comment: Thanks Jan, It was the tag bundle, your answer is correct but i've given the points to nuno.  You have my upvote and my admiration :)

Comment: Thanks John, Of course it's not about points and reputation, but about helping each other out as fellow Tridion-ees. ;)  And Nuno was first, I can't keep up with him.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, The

```
<TagBundle Resource="com/tridion/smarttarget/tcdl/tagbundle.xml"/>
```

registers handlers for the smarttarget tcdl tags in the deployer, without it the deployer will ignore the 'unknown' tags